# Retrofit2 posting form-data works android 7, not android 5

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using retrofit2 to post credentials in a multipart/form-data. The goal is to receive a session cookie.

The solution works as expected running in Android 8, but can't seem to work on older versions such as 5 - 6. I get no errors, but the server doesn't return any cookie.

The code looks something like this

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (service == null) {
            boxRestService = getService(Constants.URL);
        }

        MultipartBody mPart = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart(Constants.FORMS_USERNAME, credentials.first)
                .addFormDataPart(Constants.FORMS_PASSWORD, credentials.second).build();

        Call<ResponseBody> currentCall = service.getFormAuthCookie(mPart);
        try {
            currentCall.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("GET_AUTH_BACKGROUND", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Furthermore, the call looks as such:

```
@POST("/check/login")
Call<ResponseBody> getFormAuthCookie(@Body MultipartBody body);
```

In both platforms, retrofit produces the same (correct) post request:

```
--> POST https://website.dom/check/login http/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa
Content-Length: 258
--aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sph_username"
Username
--aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sph_password"
Password
--aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa--
--> END POST (258-byte body)
```

Since I need the cookie for the next request, this request is performed synchronously in a background thread.

For the cookie part, that I don't believe it's an issue, I'm using a JavaNetCookieJar.

The request also works fine using Advanced Rest Client.

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious.

Are those methods usable in older android versions?

Thank you very much.

-nls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out the server was redirecting the requests without my knowledge. I found this by accident while experimenting with the HTTP client options.

The solution, for this (very, very) specifit cenario, is to disable the following of redirects.

Thus, I changed the retrofit builder method to do something as follows:

```
OkHttpClient clt = new OkHttpClient().Builder()
builder.followRedirects(false)   // <-- Important!
...
.build();

Retrofit r = new Retrofit.Builder()
.client(clt)
...
.build();
```

Still don't know why it worked in newer versions of android.

Hopefully this helps anyone.

Cheers

-nls